# how to send picture bewteen two device automatically with python script? or other alternatives

Tags: python, python-3.x, send, sendmessage

if I'm planning to use raspberry pi taking the picture , and send to NVIDIA Jetson TX2 to analize, how can I do so?

environment: raspberry pi 4 , openCV, cv2, Jetson TX2 Ubuntu 18.04, Python

from now I know how to take the picture using usb camera (connected with raspberry pi 4) and save the pic on desktop

also analyze the pic by NVIDIA Jetson TX2

both can use network, my question is `how to send picture bewteen two device automatically with python script?` or `other alternatives app can do so`

now i'm sending pic manually by gmail (´-ι_-｀)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [scp](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scp-command-in-linux-with-examples/).

```bash
scp path/to/image.png username@192.168.179.100:/your/folder/
```

Replace the username and ip address with these of the jetson or raspi press enter and enter the Passwort of the user that you want to connect.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad. You have multiple solutions at hand:

- Configure a webserver on the recieving end and send the picture via HTTP (`requests` module). Have a look at `Flask` or `FastAPI`.
- Configure a FTP on the recieving end, and send the picture via a FTP module (seems like there is a [native lib for that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html)
- Others ?